# How do I stop a folder from auto opening on my external HDD?

Tags: finder

I have an external drive and whenever I open a specific folder (in list view, which is my default), it always opens one specific subfolder, one that I rarely go into. This is frustrating because the subfolder is huge and it takes a while to open, meaning I have to wait every time before I can go to the subfolder I want to.

I am on Big Sur.

Comment: Have you tried, from the Finder, to close all the lists and secondary directories of this external drive then to close and reopen this external disk in the Finder? Otherwise look in the Presentation Options (cmd + j) of the Finder for this external disk.

Comment: I close them all every time, but next time I plug in the disk, they all re-open again. I just tried cmd + j, but I don't see anything that looks relevant there (I was looking for something like "start expanded")